# Can the Sony AD-7280S burn to DVD+R Dual Layer?

Tags: dvd, compatibility

On their site it says it supports DVD-R DL burning but no mention of DVD+R. I don't see many reliable blank DVD-R DL brands in the shops (ie Verbatim) so does the Sony AD-7280S support DVD+ DL recording?

http://www.sony-optiarc.eu/products/dvddrivesdesktoppcs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It supports DVD+R9 which is another name for [DVD+R DL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD+R_DL). So: Yes, it supports DVD+R DL. *[It's completely over my head why Sony chose to call one DVD-R DL and the other DVD+R9. DVD-R DL is also called DVD-R9.]*

**Tip:** Install [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/en/home), run it and choose "Data disc". In the main window's menu bar, choose "Recorder > Device information" and choose the correct recorder drive letter. It will tell you exactly what your optical media drive is capable of.